# What does '||' mean in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    // Return YES if incoming orientation is Portrait
    // or either of the Landscapes, otherwise, return NO
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);

}
```

What does the '||' mean here?

Comment: Seriously.....? (The answer is in your own codesample)

Comment: You could easily find that out without asking here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [| operator versus || operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644953/operator-versus-operator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same thing as the C `||` operator: [logical *or*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators).

Comment: And same as in C++, Java, C#, or pretty much the majority of all common programming languages.

Comment: Yup, except the Objective-C `||` _is_ the C operator, not just the same in terms of semantics.  I thought there might be some order of precedence differences between languages, but [I guess not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) (and holy crap, I never realized `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`. I guess I've always just used parens and never ran into that issue...)

Answer (score 1):

|| is a logic 'or' operation - it returns true if at least one of its operands is true.

Moreover, if its first operand evaluates to true it returns true without evaluating its second operand.

Answer (score 1):

It's a short-circuiting logical OR.

It returns true if either `toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` or `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)`, but the second operand is only evaluated if/when the first operand is false.

Answer (score 0):

It means OR. Just the way Obj-C uses it.

|| = OR
&& = AND

Answer (score 0):

the function wil return a Boolean true if `toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` **OR** `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape()` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages (notable exceptions: Python, Ruby, etc.) || is the logical "OR" operator.

See also == (equals), != (does not equal), and && (and).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it means something different in Objective C, but in C, C++, and Java the || operator is [logical OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Answer (score 0):

Logical operator `OR`. See [here](http://gnustep.made-it.com/BG-objc/#AEN529)

Answer (score 0):

If UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait is equal to toInterfaceOrientation then it will return true, otherwise it will return the value of UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation), which may be true or false.